# Inherit the @Lazy from a parent Repository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I would like to speed up the application start time by initializing all our spring-data repositories in a lazy fashion. But so far I could not configure a parent interface with the spring-annotation @Lazy and have all specific repositories being lazily initialized.
This would mean, I have to put @Lazy to 100+ classes. Is there any other way to make this happen?

```
@Lazy
public interface AbstractRepository<T> extends Repository<T, Long> {}

public interface ThingRepository extends AbstractRepository<Thing> {}
```